# Attaching hotkeys to bookmarks

Tags: key-bindings, bookmarks

When we open bookmarks panel we see the following:

```
% Bookmark
- --------
  mark-1                         ~/work/file-1.txt
  mark-2                         ~/work/file-2.txt
  ...
  mark-n                         ~/work/file-n.txt
```

So, to open n-th file I need to click `<Down>` key n times, algorithm complexity O(n). Supposing, that n < 10, can we attach the keys from 0 to 9 to the appropriate bookmark? So it will look like this:

```
% Bookmark
- --------
0  mark-1                         ~/work/file-1.txt
1  mark-2                         ~/work/file-2.txt
  ...
9  mark-9                         ~/work/file-9.txt
```

When the user clicks the key `<n>`, the appropriate file is opened immediately. In this case the complexity becomes O(1) - the user needs to make 1 action.

Or widening the idea: the user can attach hotkeys to bookmarks, making the number of bookmarks pretty big:

```
% Bookmark
- --------
0  mark-1                         ~/work/file-1.txt
1  mark-2                         ~/work/file-2.txt
a  mark-a                         ~/work/file-a.txt
b  mark-b                         ~/work/file-b.txt
  ...
z  mark-9                         ~/work/file-z.txt
```

Comment: A common approach for quickly getting to a specific bookmark is to use `bookmark-jump` (or some variation of that command) with a completion/narrowing framework like ivy, helm, or ido.

Comment: Also not really an answer, but note that you can use a prefix argument to jump down n lines rather than repeating the down command. For example: `C-8 C-n` in the Bookmarks List buffer (or most other buffers) will jump down 8 lines.

Comment: I don't know how to but should be possible with something like [`avy`](https://github.com/abo-abo/avy) backend @abo-abo.

Comment: @kaushalmodi To go that route, I'd take a look at the avy-backed implementation of `ace-link`. That includes a number of commands to jump to "visible links" of various kinds. Should be fairly straightforward to add a variant for bookmarks in the list buffer. (Actually -- just use `avy-goto-line`....)

Comment: @glucas "just use avy-goto-line" Duh, of course! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you interested in using only the `*Bookmark List*` display to jump to bookmarks, or are you interested in jumping to them from any buffer?

**If the former**, you can bind the keys you want (`0` to `9` or whatever) in `bookmark-bmenu-mode-map` to commands that jump to particular bookmarks or to, say, the *Nth* next bookmark.  Or you can just define a command that jumps to the *Nth* next bookmark, where you provide *N* as the prefix arg.

For example:

```el
(defun my-jump-to-nth-bookmark (n)
  "Jump to the Nth bookmark after point.
N is the numeric prefix argument."
  (interactive "p")
  (save-excursion
    (next-line n)
    (bookmark-jump (bookmark-bmenu-bookmark))))
```

But if you just want a quick way to get to the line of a particular bookmark (so you can hit `RET` there), then you can use `C-s` (or any of the other, search-related quick-access commands provided by various libraries) or `SPC` with a prefix arg *N* to move down *N* lines.

**If the latter**, you can bind keys in the `global-map` to commands that jump to specific bookmarks.  Or you can just use `bookmark-jump` to jump to any bookmark, choosing the bookmark name using completion.  If all of your bookmark names have a common prefix such as `mark-` (I would not recommend that, but that seems to be your case), then completion is as quick as `TAB` *N*, e.g., `TAB 3`.

The general command to jump to a bookmark is `bookmark-jump`.  You can define your own command that jumps to a particular bookmark by passing `bookmark-jump` that bookmark name:

```el
(defun my-bmk-jump-to-mark-3 ()
  "Jump to bookmark `mark-3'."
  (interactive)
  (bookmark-jump "mark-3"))
```

---

Note: Library [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) offers many more possibilities for using bookmarks than does vanilla Emacs.
And as far as completion/narrowing for bookmark commands goes, no library offers as much as does [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles).  In particular, it extends what **Bookmark+** offers in many ways.

---

BTW, your display of `*Bookmark List*` is wrong, in showing your proposed keys in the `%` column.  That column is used for marking bookmarks (so you can act on them). It does not indicate key bindings.  Or if you are proposing that it should show a key that jumps to the bookmark on that line, then you would need to rewrite the code that displays `*Bookmark List*` accordingly.

More importantly, you would need to establish a convention of association of keys with bookmark names, such as the rudimentary one you show (key `3` corresponds to bookmark name `mark-3`). You could certainly do that for your own use, but it would not be something that would be useful for others, IMO.  Bookmarks take general names for a reason.

Comment: I want it to be just in the buffer. It would be incorrect to have <9> key to open a buffer for me when I'm editing a file.

Answer (score 3):

Just to highlight another approach from the comments: you can use a library such as `ace-jump` or `avy`. These libraries are not specific to bookmarks, but provide a general way to jump to a specific location in the visible window.

For example, with `avy` you could use the command `avy-goto-line`. When invoked this command adds a number or character (depending on configuration) to each visible line. You can use that prefix to jump directly to a specific line.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a direct answer but you can use register:

```el
(set-register ?e '(file . "~/.emacs"))
(set-register ?b '(file . "~/.bashrc"))
(set-register ?c '(file . "~/.emacs.d/lisp/custom.el"))
```

Then C-x r j give the list you wants