# Can't establish a hook for bookmark-bmenu-mode

Tags: key-bindings, bookmarks

Trying to solve the [problem of hotkeys for bookmarks](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/17402/2389) I decided to create a primitive version first. I wanted to attach bookmarks to keys `<1>` and `<2>`: when a certain key is pressed, I open the appropriate bookmark. But unfortunately the hook is not called when bookmarks list is opened. I have different functions bound to these keys:

- 1 - bookmark-bmenu-1-window
- 2 - bookmark-bmenu-2-window

#### Code

```
(defun jump-to-1th-bookmark ()
  (bookmark-jump "2015.txt"))

(defun jump-to-2nd-bookmark ()
  (bookmark-jump "emd"))

(defun my-bookmark-mode ()
      (local-set-key (kbd "1") 'jump-to-1th-bookmark)
      (local-set-key (kbd "2") 'jump-to-2nd-bookmark)
      )

(add-hook 'bookmark-bmenu-mode 'my-bookmark-mode)
```

How can I bind my functions instead of default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just bind the keys in the keymap used by the mode of buffer `*Bookmark List*`.

This is what mode keymaps are for.  There is no need to use the mode hook.

```el
(with-eval-after-load "bookmark"
  (define-key bookmark-bmenu-mode-map (kbd "1") 'jump-to-1th-bookmark)
  (define-key bookmark-bmenu-mode-map (kbd "2") 'jump-to-2nd-bookmark))
```

Comment: I upgraded your code to the working version. Please, feel free to upgrade it further: maybe, it would be possible to get rid of the hook.

Comment: @user4035 There was no hook in Drew's answer, and it works, I just tested it.

Comment: @T.Verron I tried his - didn't work for me on GNU Emacs 24.2.1 .

Comment: @user4035 What was the error? If it is `unknown variable: bookmark-bmenu-mode-map`, could you test it with the `(require 'bookmark)` line?

Comment: @T.Verron Tried - works. But adding `(require 'bookmark)` is obligatory, doesn't work without it.

Comment: @user4035 Keeping the line in your config shouldn't cause any problem. If you don't want to use bookmarks in all of your emacs sessions, you can also wrap the `define-key` lines in an `eval-after-load` form, so that it is evaluated the first time you use one of the bookmarks functions. Using the hook, the lines would be evaluated each time you enter the `bookmark-bmenu-mode`, which could prove annoying (for example if you want to redefine these keys).

Comment: I restored my original answer. The point is that you do not need to use a mode hook to add a binding to a mode map. You do need to have the map defined, of course, which typically means that you need to have the library loaded. I added an explicit `eval-after-load` to make that clear.

Comment: @Drew I simply fixed the syntax..it needs to be `with-eval-after-load`. The older `eval-after-load` needs a quoted form.

Comment: @kaushalmodi: Oh, right. I meant to quote and use `progn`. But `with...` is OK too.