# Are keybindings mode-dependent? How can I customize this?

Tags: key-bindings, functions

I have bound the `eval-region` function to `H-x`

I would like to use this to simply highlight selected code and evaluate - simple.

Working in a Python script I have the following code:

```
def test(this, that):
    output = this * that
    return output

print test(2,4)
```

When I highlight it and press `H-x`, I get the error message: **"Symbols' value as variable is void: def"**

Still having the same code highlighted, in the Python dropdown in the menu bar I click on "eval region" and I get the expected output (i.e. `8`).

I have seen [an explanation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Void-Variables.html) of void variables, but I don't really understand it all - I just want `H-x` to perform `eval-region` as clicking on the menu-bar version does.

Does anyone know a fix, work-around or the required setup?

Comment: `eval-region` evaluates only elisp code AFAIK. To see exactly what command is called by the dropdown menu, first hit `C-h c` or `C-h k` and then click that menu item.

Comment: Thanks - it executes (in this case) `python-shell-send-region`.
@kaushalmodi - do you how I could best get the functionality I am looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is to change what `H-x` does when in `python-mode` so that instead of running `eval-region` (which only works on elisp) it calls `python-shell-send-region`.  You can use `define-key` to do this:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'python
  (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "H-x") #'python-shell-send-region))
```

Comment: Is having this in my .emacs a bad idea, as it is causing an error which I cannot solve. **"Symbol's value as variable is void: python-mode-map"**.
It seems to require a python session to already be in existence - it works if I evaluate at that point. How can I get around this in emacs' initialisation?

Comment: @DexterMorgan: The problem is that the variable `python-mode-map` is defined when `python-mode` is loaded, and your `.emacs` executes this line *before* that happened. Please see [this answer to a recent question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17414/2355). The comments to this answer address exactly the issue you describe.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @erikstokes is the correct one (hence why I have accepted it), however in order to get it to work in my init (.emacs) file, I had to define it first as a hook.

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "H-x")
                        'python-shell-send-region)))
```

This allows it to load and then be called upon in python-mode, and doesn't require a python-mode to already be active (hence making in work from my one large init file. [I know it makes sense to break an init file up into sub-files, but I haven't got round to that yet]

Comment: You simply need to first require the package before calling this `add-hook`. If you are using `use-package`, you add that `add-hook` in the `:config` block of `use-package`.

Comment: Or.. you can put that `add-hook` in  `(with-eval-after-load 'PACKAGE-NAME .. )`.

Comment: Is there a big difference/benefit to your suggestion? My way wouldn't require anything at intialisation and so I would expect faster...?

Comment: `with-eval-after-load` doesn't need any initialization.. it's just one wrapper around the `define-key` *(I realized that I wrote `add-hook` in my earlier 2 comments instead of `define-key`; that was a mistake.)* .. Adding that `define-key` to `python-mode-hook` will unnecessary run that `define-key` each time you switch to a `python-mode` buffer or even simply revert that buffer. I find that very inefficient. `define-key` wrapped with `with-eval-after-load` will look very much cleaner and will execute just once when the `python-mode` gets loaded.

Comment: I have updated the answer by **@erikstokes** with `with-eval-after-load`.

Comment: This redefines the keybinding each time a python buffer is opened.